# Check TextView is full or not

Tags: android, textview

I want to check dynamically if textView is full or not with given text.
i.e. In a TextView I assign Text dynamically. and also I want to check whether that TextView is full of text with given text or not. and that textview lies in custom listview.
my textview is having max line 3.

Comment: if textview full then what?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

you need to calculate the size of your textview and the size of your text. 
Try this to find size of your text view

```
int text_view_size = text_view.getLayoutParams().width;
```

and this for finding the size of your text

```
 int text_size = getTextSize(text_view.getText().toString());
```

this is getTextSize method

```
private int getTextSize(String your_text){
    Paint p = new Paint();
    //Calculate the text size in pixel
    return p.measureText(your_text);
}
```

Now you can check using text watTextWatcher class that your text exceeds the size of your text view.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher to see when the text has changed :

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       //This sets a textview to the current length
       mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }};
```

Also check this :[TextWatcher example](http://khaled-bakhit.com/blog/2013/03/15/android-how-to-display-live-count-of-number-of-characters-left-in-edittext/)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if(textView.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0)
{
      //here your textview has no text
}
```